# SQL coding for group and sum with multiple tables and where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am fairly new to SQL. Here is my end goal:

sum of hours worked by calendar day by caregiver after 12/31/15

Here is the code I have now

```
select br_ID, car_ID, car_FirstName, car_LastName, car_SkillCd, car_Role, car_EmpSubCod_UD, schst_Name, svcc_Name, dbo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sch_StartTime , tz_Data), dbo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sch_endtime , tz_Data), sch_Units, sch_PayDate, sch_PayUnits, cli_LastName, cli_FirstName 
from T_Schedules
inner join T_Branches on br_ID = sch_BranchID
inner join T_TimeZones on tz_ID = br_TimeZoneID
Full outer join T_Caregiver ON T_schedules.sch_CaregiverID = T_Caregiver.car_ID
full outer join T_ServiceCode on T_Schedules.sch_ServiceCodeID = T_ServiceCode.svcc_ID
full outer join T_ScheduleStatus on T_schedules.sch_ScheduleStatusID = T_ScheduleStatus.schst_ID
full outer join T_Client on T_Schedules.sch_ClientID = T_Client.cli_ID
where sch_ScheduleStatusID = 3 and dbo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sch_StartTime , tz_Data) >= '2016-01-01'
```

Anyone know how to group the hours by caregiver. I can't just sum the scheduled units because if it's an overnight shift, those hours could be split between 2 calendar days.

Comment: And why would you be using `full outer join`?

Comment: Are sch_StartTime and sch_EndTime DateTime values?

Comment: Yes, sch_StartTime and sch_Endtime are date time values written at yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:000

Answer (score 0):

The overnight shift is a bit of a problem and most likely will skew your results.
Unless you go back and assoicate 1/2 the shift to one day and 1/2 to the other day there is nothing SQL can do for you. (I think) How I would approach this is a simple group by and see if that is good enough:

```
SELECT dbo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sch_StartTime , tz_Data), 
br_ID, car_ID, car_FirstName, 
car_LastName, car_SkillCd, car_Role, 
car_EmpSubCod_UD, schst_Name, svcc_Name, 
dbo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sch_endtime , tz_Data), 
SUM(sch_Units), 
sch_PayDate, sch_PayUnits, cli_LastName, cli_FirstName 
FROM T_Schedules
INNER JOIN T_Branches on br_ID = sch_BranchID
INNER JOIN T_TimeZones on tz_ID = br_TimeZoneID
FULL OUTER JOIN T_Caregiver ON T_schedules.sch_CaregiverID = T_Caregiver.car_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN T_ServiceCode on T_Schedules.sch_ServiceCodeID = T_ServiceCode.svcc_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN T_ScheduleStatus on T_schedules.sch_ScheduleStatusID = T_ScheduleStatus.schst_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN T_Client on T_Schedules.sch_ClientID = T_Client.cli_ID

WHERE sch_ScheduleStatusID = 3 and dbo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sch_StartTime , tz_Data) >= '2016-01-01'

GROUP BY [sch_StartTime]
```

Comment: You've got several fields in the select that aren't in an aggregate function or in the group by

Comment: very good point, sorry I was trying to be quick with it. Make sure when you paste this you include that in the group by.

Answer (score 0):

The problem: A shift from `sch_StartTime` to `sch_endtime` can be over midnight, so some hours were worked on one day and some on the next.

We write two queries: one for the first day and one for the next and then glue both sets together with `UNION ALL`. Here is the query built step by step with `WITH` clauses:

```
with worked as
(
  select 
    sch_caregiverid as caregiverid,
    dbo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sch_StartTime, tz_Data) as starttime,
    dbo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sch_endtime, tz_Data) as endtime
  from T_Schedules
  where sch_ScheduleStatusID = 3 and dbo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sch_StartTime , tz_Data) >= '2016-01-01'
)
, day1 as
(
  select
    caregiverid,
    starttime, 
    case when day(starttime) <> day(endtime) then 
      datetimefromparts(year(starttime), month(starttime), day(starttime), 23, 59, 59, 999)
    else 
      endtime
    end as endtime
  from worked
)
, day2 as
(
  select 
    caregiverid,
    datetimefromparts(year(endtime), month(endtime), day(endtime), 0, 0, 0, 0) as starttime, 
    endtime
  from worked
  where day(starttime) <> day(endtime)
)
, bothdays as
(
  select caregiverid, starttime, endtime from day1
  union all
  select caregiverid, starttime, endtime from day2
)
, hours_worked as
(
  select 
    caregiverid, 
    convert(date, starttime) as whichday, 
    sum(datediff(hour, starttime, endtime)) as total
  from bothdays
  group by caregiverid, convert(date, starttime)
)
select *
from t_caregiver 
join hours_worked on hours_worked.caregiverid = t_caregiver.car_id;
```